# Using COUNT(*) in Hibernate with Read_Uncommitted always blocked

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am using MYSQL and Hibernate + Spring with Annotation Transaction. To test read_uncommitted, I run two threads, one to modify a row 20 times on the table, the other to count the total number of rows of that table. Although I set the transaction level to read_uncommitted, the read total count thread is always blocked until the modifying thread is finished.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-hibernate.xml");

        WarehouseService service = ctx.getBean("warehouseServiceImpl", WarehouseService.class);

        System.out.println("Table initialized");

        int prodId = 3;

       //By default, increment product inventory 5 at a time, repeat 10 times
        IncreaseInventoryThread thrdIncInvent = new IncreaseInventoryThread(service, prodId, 10);
        thrdIncInvent.start();
        System.out.println("Total product: "+service.countAllProducts());
}
```

My IncreaseInventoryThread simply calling increaseInventory method 20 times

```
public class IncreaseInventoryThread extends Thread {

    WarehouseService service;
    int prodId;
    int iteration;


    public IncreaseInventoryThread(WarehouseService service, int prodId, int iteration) {
        this.service = service;
        this.prodId = prodId;
        this.iteration = iteration;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<iteration; i++){
            service.increaseInventory(prodId);          
        }
    }
}
```

My service class simply do modifying, and read total count. All transactions are defined here

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, readOnly=false)
    public void increaseInventory(int prodId) {
        productDao.addInvetory(prodId, DEFAULT_INC_INVENTORY);
        Product product = productDao.getProductById(prodId);
        System.out.println(product.getName()+" now has " + product.getStock());         
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED, readOnly=true)
    public int countAllProducts() {
        System.out.println("Transaction begins for counting");
        return (productDao.getTotalProduct());
    }
```

My DAO is follows:

```
@Repository
public class HibernateProductDao implements ProductDao {

    @Autowired 
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public Session currentSession() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInvetory(int id, int quantity) {

        Product product = getProductById(id);
        int newStock = product.getStock()+quantity;
        product.setStock(newStock);
        addProduct(product);

    }

    @Override
    public int getTotalProduct() {
        int total = 0;
        String hql = "SELECT count(product.id) FROM Product product ";
        Query query = currentSession().createQuery(hql);
        total = ((Number)query.uniqueResult()).intValue();
        return total;
    }

}
```

But In my result, total count always wait until all increaseInventory transaction finished.

```
Table initialized
Transaction begins for counting
TV Set now has 105
TV Set now has 110
TV Set now has 115
TV Set now has 120
TV Set now has 125
TV Set now has 130
TV Set now has 135
TV Set now has 140
TV Set now has 145
TV Set now has 150
Total product: 7
```

Anybody knows why is that? isn't read_uncommitted doesn't require X-lock

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />    

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cmpt.project.persistence"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cmpt.project.service"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db"></property>
        <property name="username" value="xxxx"></property>
        <property name="password" value="xxxx"></property> 
        <property name="initialSize" value="5"></property>
        <property name="maxActive" value="10"></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="packagesToScan"
            value="com.cmpt.project.model">
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Comment: What happens if you change the isolation level of the 'writer' ?  , from the code is isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, maybe if you hack  both reader & writer to use read uncommitted semantics, you won't see blocking behavior

Comment: I checked, but it makes no difference. Weird thing is if I have a thread to write and another just to read a row, two threads can be interleaving. But if I change the read row thread to get total count, it waits until all write operations are done.

Comment: Post the configuration for your datasource.